# Python generated zlib + base64 text getting incorrect header check exception in Java

Tags: java, compression, zlib

I am required to write a consumer in Java from Kafka streams, publisher app is written by a third party in python. When I use base64 decoding and then zlip uncompress in java, I get an incorrect header check exception.

My Task is: Convert this compressed base64 + zlib data into a text file that is readable.

Publisher's code in python:

```
 # read in the file content
   inputf=open(file, 'rb')
   input=inputf.read()
   inputf.close()
   # using zlib.compress(s) method
   compressed = zlib.compress(input)
   # encoding with base64 encoding
   encoding_type='base64'
   enc_data=encode(compressed,encoding_type)
   enc_data_utf8=enc_data.decode("utf-8")
#   enc_data=enc_data_no_no_newline                      ####[0:86000]       #   trim
   event_etl_event[filename+"_content"]=enc_data_utf8
   event_etl_event[filename+"_compressed_format"]="zlib+uuencode"
    enter code here
```

Consumer Code in java

public void processData(){

```
   inputStr = event.getEventEtlEvent().getAllProblemsTxtContent();
        
        
        System.out.println("Before Base64 decoding: \n" + inputStr);
        
         Path path0 = Paths.get("AllProblems_Before_base64_decoding.txt");
         Files.write(path0, inputStr.getBytes());
          
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        String decodedString = new String(base64.decode(inputStr.getBytes()));
        
        System.out.println("After Base64 decode: \n" + decodedString);
        
         Path path1 = Paths.get("AllProblems_After_base64_decoding.txt");
         Files.write(path1, decodedString.getBytes());
          
        System.out.println("now zlib 64 decodingString .........\n\n\n");
        
        byte[] output = ZLibUtils.decompress(decodedString.getBytes());  

        System.out.println("After Zlib Decompress: "+ output);

        
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /*catch (InvalidDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DataFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ZLibUtils.java

```
  public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws DataFormatException {  
            byte[] output = new byte[0];  
    
            Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();  
            decompresser.reset();  
            decompresser.setInput(data);  
    
            ByteArrayOutputStream o = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);  
           // try {  
                byte[] buf = new byte[data.length]; 
                byte[] a = new byte[data.length];
                while (!decompresser.finished()) {  
                    int i = decompresser.inflate(buf);  
                    o.write(buf, 0, i);  
                }  
                output = o.toByteArray();  
                /* } catch (Exception e) {  
                output = data;  
                e.printStackTrace();  
                //FIXME: in later code
                System.exit(0);
            } finally {  
                try {  
                    o.close();  
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }  */
    
            decompresser.end();  
            return output;  
        }
```

Now when I run my program, i get the following exception:

```
    java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:280)
        at com.exmple.util.ZLibUtils.decompress(ZLibUtils.java:84

)
```

Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: You need consistency in character encoding. They are using UTF-8 so you should be using `String.getBytes("UTF-8");` Avoid redundant steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you convert the base64 decoded data from a byte array into a string and back into a byte array. For most encodings this is **not** a **no-op**. That means, for most encodings and most byte arrays,

```
byte[] decoded = { (byte) 0x9b, 1, 2, 3 };
String decodedString = new String(decoded);
byte[] processed = decodedString.getBytes();
```

the contents of processed will be different from the contents of decoded.

The solution is to **not** treat the base64 decoded data as string and instead of that work with the byte data directly:

```
    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    byte[] decoded = base64.decode(inputStr.getBytes());
    
    Path path1 = Paths.get("AllProblems_After_base64_decoding.txt");
    Files.write(path1, decoded);
      
    System.out.println("now zlib 64 decodingString .........\n\n\n");
    
    byte[] output = ZLibUtils.decompress(decoded);
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, the generated text files is now readable and no errors